Adding automatic diffstat for last change to magit status buffer
I would like my Magit status buffer to display a diffstat of recent changes at the bottom. Ideally, this would be like the diffstat shown by git pull when the merge.stat option is true—a diffstat between ORIG_HEAD and the current results. What's the best way to do this?

Magit does not offer that feature. You can implement it yourself by copy-pasting code that does something similar and adjusting it to your needs.
After looking at magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream and magit-insert-diff, I came up with:
(defun my-magit-insert-diffstat-unpushed-to-upstream ()
  (when-let ((upstream (magit-get-upstream-branch)))
    (magit-insert-section (upstream-stat "@{upstream}..")
      (magit--insert-diff t "diff" "--stat" "@{upstream}.."))))

(magit-add-section-hook 'magit-status-sections-hook
                        #'my-magit-insert-diffstat-unpushed-to-upstream
                        #'magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream-or-recent t)

If this isn't displaying the differences you want, then replace "@{upstream}.." with something else (other adjustments are also in order of course). Look, e.g., at other functions defined in the neighborhood of magit-insert-unpushed-to-upstream for inspiration.
